# Showing syntax error in this code

Tags: php

I tested this code in WAMP server

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root","")  or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);
    mysql_select_db ("movedb");

    $values = new Array();
    $i = 0;
    $text = $_POST['jam'];
    $arrayText = explode(" ", $text);
    foreach($arrayText as $val) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WORD WHERE ENGLISH = '$val'");
        while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $values[$s] = $r['SINHALA'];
            $i++;
        }
    }

    foreach($values as $val) {
        echo $val.' ';
    }
?>
```

but showing this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Array' (T_ARRAY)
```

Comment: This is not JavaScript. Use `$values = array();` Also, your `$s` is not defined and you are still using [deprecated `mysql_` functions](http://goo.gl/J5jAo).

Comment: If using PHP 5.4+ you can use `$values = [];` as well

Answer (score 4):

use just this

```
$values = array();
```

Comment: WORKING . TNX FOR QUICK RESPONSE

Answer (score 2):

```
 $values[$s] = $r['SINHALA'];
```

this should be

```
$values[$i] = $r['SINHALA'];
```

and

```
$values = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

**$s** is neither initialized nor incremented, its not being used. You need correction on **$s**. Make it **$i**.

Change :

```
$values[$s] = $r['SINHALA'];
```

to

```
$values[$i] = $r['SINHALA'];
```